# Product Grid show raw HTML code. Need Help about Ui Component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, product-grid

I join my custom table and add column to Product Grid as Ui_Component text. But it show data in raw code.

How to make it show as HTML code?

[image]

Ui_Component setting

```
<columns name="product_columns"> 
<column name="hub_stock" sortOrder="76">
    <settings>
        <addField>true</addField>
        <filter>text</filter>
        <label translate="true">Hub Stock</label>
    </settings>
</column>
```

I also add line break in database but it still show in the same row on mangeto.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.
https://newbedev.com/rendering-a-html-tag-in-grid-magento-2

Add this to Ui_Component column

```
<item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
```